# ssh causing pulseaudio not to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, pulse-audio

I did setup pulse audio to forward the audio of the raspberry pi to my pc. However I have disabled network access on the pi using paprefs.  I don't need to redirect the audio since I have a separate pair of speakers connected to the pi. However this doesn't work as I get an error when using ssh to x forward.

I use x forward so that I can remotely edit the python scripts using Thonny which is installed on the raspberry pi. However I can't do this now because my python app wont work because pulse audio isn't working

However the error doesn't occur if I start my python app via a terminal on the raspberry pi itself via vnc.

```
vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried with make discoverable pulse audio network sound devices available locally on and off.

Comment: Maybe I'm having a blond moment, but are you saying that audio over the network doesn't work since you disabled it while it works locally, and that that surprises you?

Comment: no. I don't need to redirect the audio now because I have a separate set of speakers plugged into the pi. However since I disabled the network access, I am getting errors when trying to use vlc so I don't get any audio out of the speakers connected to the pi. but this is only a problem when x forward using ssh